# AirPrint contents of a UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, airprint, uiprintformatter

I'm trying to set up printing through an iPad app, where clicking Print will print a view with all of its contents. Here's what I've tried (pulled together from a few examples online):

```
// This is the View I want to print
// Just a 200x200 blue square
var testView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))
testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)!
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General
printInfo.jobName = "My Print Job"

// Set up print controller
let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()
printController!.printInfo = printInfo
// This is where I was thinking the print job got the
// contents to print to the page??
printController?.printFormatter = testView.viewPrintFormatter()

// Do it
printController!.presentFromRect(self.frame, inView: self, animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```

However, I also read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewPrintFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIViewPrintFormatter) that `viewPrintFormatter` is only available to UIWebView, UITextView, and MKMapView, is that correct?

When I print with this (using the printer simulator) I just get an empty page; tried with various printers/paper sizes.

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: My bad - updated question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it, but I ended up solving this by converting the view to a `UIImage` and then setting it as the print controller's `printingItem`.

Updated code:

```
// This is the View I want to print
// Just a 200x200 blue square
var testView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))
testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)!
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputType.General
printInfo.jobName = "My Print Job"

// Set up print controller
let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.sharedPrintController()
printController!.printInfo = printInfo

// Assign a UIImage version of my UIView as a printing iten
printController?.printingItem = testView!.toImage()

// Do it
printController!.presentFromRect(self.frame, inView: self, animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
```

The `toImage()` method is an extension to UIView:

```
extension UIView {
    func toImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

        drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Open to alternative approaches if anyone has one!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe someone (like me) needs to add border to the imageview before send it to the printer (otherwise the image will automatically fits to the sheet). I searched for some build-in methods in order to do this, but I haven't found it (btw, I read some hints from [here](http://nshipster.com/uiprintinteractioncontroller/)).
The trick is to add the view containing the image to an external view, and then center it.

```
    let borderWidth: CGFloat = 100.0
    let myImage = UIImage(named: "myImage.jpg")
    let internalPrintView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height))
    let printView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, myImage.size.width + borderWidth*2, myImage.size.height + borderWidth*2))
    internalPrintView.image = myImage
    internalPrintView.center = CGPointMake(printView.frame.size.width/2, printView.frame.size.height/2)
    printView.addSubview(internalPrintView)
    printController.printingItem = printView.toImage()
```

It's a little bit complex but it does its dirty job.